# Why NSArray does not have a firstObject method?

Tags: objective-c, ios

But it does have a lastObject, anybody know why?

Comment: there's even a blog:
http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/02/adding-firstobject-to-nsarray/

Comment: According to one of my buddies, there has actually been an -[NSArray firstObject] for a long time, it's just been private.

Comment: It doesn't have a `-secondObject` or `-thirdObject` either.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

My guess is because `lastObject` reduces more boilerplate code. You use `[array lastObject]` to replace either `[array objectAtIndex:array.count - 1]` or `array[array.count - 1]` using modern Objective-C syntax.

Whereas in the case of `firstObject` you can simply check `[array objectAtIndex:0]` or `array[0]`.
It just helps streamline things to be able to call `lastObject` instead of typing out that function.

## Update

As @Nathaniel Symer suggested in his comment above, `firstObject` has previously been available but only in private API (I believe since iOS 4). However, as of the release of the iOS 7 SDK, `firstObject` is now publicly available!

Comment: I was going to say the same think, last object actually queries for the object with the highest index, which is why there is a convenience method for it.

Comment: Yes thank you. that's very possible. I just feel kind of "unbalance" when using both  [myArray objectAtIndex:0]  and [myArray lastObject] ...

Comment: @NSPostWhenIdle sure I will:) but plz allow me to wait a moment to see if there is any other ideas

Comment: Funny that they added `-firstObject` to the public API *after* giving us the (awesome) array index notation. I don't know why you'd use `[array firstObject]` when `array[0]` is shorter and about as readable.

Comment: @0x7fffffff In fairness, it does nicely balance `-lastObject`, so maybe it'll be more readable in that context.

Comment: @Caleb There is a big difference between `[array firstObject]` and `array[0]`. The first returns nil and the second throws an exception when the array is empty. Assuming that `firstObject` works similarly to `lastObject` (I didn't read the docs yet).

Comment: @ErikB Great point -- I hadn't considered that. Thanks.

Comment: According to the docs `firstObject` is "Available in iOS 4.0 and later."

Comment: Here's the docs that say iOS 4.0 or later: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/firstObject

Comment: @reecon & funroll: But it's not in the public headers until the iOS 7 SDK. Assuming the method was actually there, and that Apple does not do private-method checks against older OS versions, then I guess it would be safe to add it in a category (if building against an older SDK). Anyone know for sure?

Comment: @big_m As far as I understand it's ok to send `-firstObject` message to the object if you're building with iOS 7 SDK and targeting older versions down to iOS 4. Tested it on OS X 10.8 with project built with OS X 10.10 SDK (this method was introduced in OS X 10.9 SDK).